# Jasperserver - How to connect to my 000webhost mysql

Tags: mysql, jasperserver

I'm starting learning jasperserver but I have a problem: I want to create a data source that connects to a mysql in my 000webhost account, but I'm getting a problem `Could not connect to mysql7.000webhost.com:3306 : Connection timed out Show Details` here is the screenshots:
[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Are you allowed to remotely connect to your mysql database at all?

Comment: I don't know, How to check it out?

Comment: Ask their support...